# How to address multiple cases in this BVP? (Laplace equation in quarter-annulus)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> The original problem:
>   $$\nabla^2 u =0 \ \ \ \   for \ \ \ 0<a<r<b\ \ \  ,\ \ \ 0<\theta <\frac \pi 2$$
>   $$u(r,0)=0,\ \  u(r,\frac \pi 2)=f(r),\ \  u(a,\theta)=u(b,\theta)=0$$

**My question pertains to the ODE for $G(r)$, found after separation $u=G(r) \Theta (\theta)$ and how this affects the solution to the overall PDE.**

$$r^2 G_{rr} + rG_r - \lambda G = 0$$

$$\lambda = -(\frac{n\pi}{ln b/a})^2$$ where $\lambda$ has been derived in the post.

I've run into a wall with this separated radial ODE. I've actually finished this entire problem and reached the back of the book answer, but I found some beguiling cases that seem to flaw the solution. To see the cases, please scroll down. **The answer in the back of the book does not seem to take into account these other cases, and I want to see if all cases simplify into the same answer or not.**

---

Here's my general solution to the ODE with $\lambda$ substituted in the second line:

$$G(r) = A\cos\left(\sqrt{|\lambda|} \ln r\right) + B\sin\left(\sqrt{|\lambda|} \ln r\right)$$

$$ = A\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r\right) + B\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r\right)$$

Here are the boundary conditions, $G(b)=G(a)=0$:

$$A\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln a\right) + B\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln a\right) = 0$$
$$A\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln b\right) + B\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln b\right) = 0$$

---

**EDIT2:** Solving $\lambda$, where $\lambda <0$ proven elsewhere. From the BCs above note that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\left(\sqrt{|\lambda|}\ln a\right) & \sin\left(\sqrt{|\lambda|} \ln a\right) \\ 
    \cos\left(\sqrt{|\lambda|} \ln b\right) & \sin\left(\sqrt{|\lambda|} \ln b\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    A\\
B
\end{bmatrix} =0
$$
$$\implies \sin(\sqrt{|\lambda|} ln(b/a)) = 0 \implies \lambda = -(\frac{n\pi}{ln b/a})^2$$

---

**Here's where the issue arises: I need to resolve the coeffcients of G(r). Can I put $A$ in terms of $B$ without creating multiple cases?** If the terms were nonzero, it'd be easy. We'd use either equation (say the top one) to derive

$$A = -B\tan\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln a\right)$$

which eventually leads to

$$G(r) = C\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r/a\right)$$

**This last line leads to the back of the book answer (scroll down, see CASE1). But it's not clear if we are actually permitted to divide our terms and get $A = -B\tan\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln a\right)$! What if a term was zero?** The terms cannot be simultaneously zero, since sine and cosine are orthogonal, but suppose one of them, say $\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln a\right)=0$. Then $B=0$ and we get **CASE2**

$$G(r) = A\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r\right) $$

But then the remaining BC gives a funny result

$$G(b) = A\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln b\right) = 0$$

$\implies n\pi\frac{\ln b}{\ln b/a} = \frac{\pi}{2}(2k+1)$ for a nontrivial solution. But... that depends on the value of $b$!!! It doesn't appear that $b$ always has to satisfy this... does it? This has me scratching my head.

*UPDATE: SRX's answer clarifies this point. This makes sense.*

There is similarly a **CASE3** with $G(r) = B\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r\right) $.

---

**What's left to find out is whether or not these cases simplify to the same overall solution. Or, whether we need cases at all!**

The solution to the azimuthal ODE is $\Theta (\theta) = \sinh(\frac{n \pi \theta}{\ln b/a})$. Take my word for it. This gives three cases of solutions:

> **CASE1:**
>   $$u_1(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r/a\right) \sinh \left(\frac{n \pi \theta}{\ln b/a}\right)$$
>   $$C_n \sinh \left(\frac{n \pi^2}{2\ln (b/a)}\right) = \frac{2}{\ln(b/a)} \int^b_a f(r) \sin \left(n \pi \frac{\ln (r/a)}{\ln (b/a)}\right) \frac{dr}{r}$$

**CASE2:**
$$u_2(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r\right) \sinh \left(\frac{n \pi \theta}{\ln b/a}\right)$$

**CASE3**
$$u_3(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{\ln b/a} \ln r\right) \sinh \left(\frac{n \pi \theta}{\ln b/a}\right)$$

As mentioned earlier, only CASE1 appears in the back of the textbook as an answer. The coefficients were found after applying the final BC $u(r,\frac \pi 2) = f(r)$ and taking a weighted inner product with weight $1/r$. I'll exclude the work for now and only cite the result for CASE1. The coefficient relations for $A_n$ and $B_n$ don't seem to work out very nicely. I had issues with them and will need to re-explore those.

Am I crazy, or does this problem split into these three separate solutions? I see how, physically speaking, CASE1 is of greatest interest as it would occur more commonly, but what about CASES 2 and 3?

Comment: Could you update with the exact ode you are looking at?

Comment: Can you please also add how you work out the spectrum $\lambda$?

Comment: @SRX added it at the bottom. Also, I had a typo. Note that the first four lines under the line break are now $Acos() + Bsin()$, where there is now a plus sign... not a minus. I don't think it changes match, though, since the unsolved constants were still there.

Comment: You should match both $r$ and $\theta$ .

Comment: Please refer to how the EqWorld plays: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde301.pdf

Comment: @doraemonpaul Thank you for the detailed replies.  I've been a bit busy these past days, but I will study your answer this week. It has not gone unnoticed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u_{rr}+\dfrac{u_r}{r}+\dfrac{u_{\theta\theta}}{r^2}=0$

Let $\begin{cases}r_1=\ln r\\\theta_1=\theta\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_r=u_{r_1}(r_1)_r+u_{\theta_1}(\theta_1)_r=\dfrac{u_{r_1}}{r}=e^{-r_1}u_{r_1}$

$u_{rr}=(e^{-r_1}u_{r_1})_r=(e^{-r_1}u_{r_1})_{r_1}(r_1)_r+(e^{-r_1}u_{r_1})_{\theta_1}(\theta_1)_r=(e^{-r_1}u_{r_1r_1}-e^{-r_1}u_{r_1})e^{-r_1}=e^{-2r_1}u_{r_1r_1}-e^{-2r_1}u_{r_1}$

$u_\theta=u_{r_1}(r_1)_\theta+u_{\theta_1}(\theta_1)_\theta=u_{\theta_1}$

$u_{\theta\theta}=(u_{\theta_1})_\theta=(u_{\theta_1})_{r_1}(r_1)_\theta+(u_{\theta_1})_{\theta_1}(\theta_1)_\theta=u_{\theta_1\theta_1}$

$\therefore e^{-2r_1}u_{r_1r_1}-e^{-2r_1}u_{r_1}+e^{-2r_1}u_{r_1}+e^{-2r_1}u_{\theta_1\theta_1}=0$ for $\ln a<r_1<\ln b$ , $0<\theta_1<\dfrac {\pi}{2}$

$u_{r_1r_1}+u_{\theta_1\theta_1}=0$ for $\ln a<r_1<\ln b$ , $0<\theta_1<\dfrac {\pi}{2}$

Let $\begin{cases}r_2=r_1-\ln a\\\theta_2=\theta_1\end{cases}$ ,

Then $u_{r_1}=u_{r_2}(r_2)_{r_1}+u_{\theta_2}(\theta_2)_{r_1}=u_{r_2}$

$u_{r_1r_1}=(u_{r_2})_{r_1}=(u_{r_2})_{r_2}(r_2)_{r_1}+(u_{r_2})_{\theta_2}(\theta_2)_{r_1}=u_{r_2r_2}$

$u_{\theta_1}=u_{r_2}(r_2)_{\theta_1}+u_{\theta_2}(\theta_2)_{\theta_1}=u_{\theta_2}$

$u_{\theta_1\theta_1}=(u_{\theta_2})_{\theta_1}=(u_{\theta_2})_{r_2}(r_2)_{\theta_1}+(u_{\theta_2})_{\theta_2}(\theta_2)_{\theta_1}=u_{\theta_2\theta_2}$

$\therefore u_{r_2r_2}+u_{\theta_2\theta_2}=0$ for $0<r_2<\ln b-\ln a$ , $0<\theta_2<\dfrac {\pi}{2}$

With reference to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde301.pdf#page=2 , we have special consideration:

$u(r_2,\theta_2)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh(2n(\ln b-\ln a-r_2))\sin 2n\theta_2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh2nr_2\sin 2n\theta_2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi r_2}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{\ln b-\ln a}\left(\dfrac {\pi}{2}-\theta_2\right)\right)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi r_2}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi\theta_2}{\ln b-\ln a}$

$u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh(2n(\ln b-\ln r))\sin 2n\theta+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh(2n(\ln r-\ln a))\sin 2n\theta+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi(\pi-2\theta)}{2\ln b-2\ln a}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi\theta}{\ln b-\ln a}$

The advantage of this consideration is that each condition only depends on one of the terms in above respectively.

$u(a,\theta)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty A(n)\sinh(2n(\ln b-\ln a))\sin 2n\theta=0$

$A(n)=0$

$\therefore u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh(2n(\ln r-\ln a))\sin 2n\theta+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi(\pi-2\theta)}{2\ln b-2\ln a}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi\theta}{\ln b-\ln a}$

$u(b,\theta)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty B(n)\sinh(2n(\ln b-\ln a))\sin 2n\theta=0$

$B(n)=0$

$\therefore u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi(\pi-2\theta)}{2\ln b-2\ln a}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi\theta}{\ln b-\ln a}$

$u(r,0)=0$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty C(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi^2}{2\ln b-2\ln a}=0$

$C(n)=0$

$\therefore u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi\theta}{\ln b-\ln a}$

$u\left(r,\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)=f(r)$ :

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi^2}{2\ln b-2\ln a}=f(r)$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty D(n)\sinh\dfrac{n\pi^2}{2\ln b-2\ln a}\sin\dfrac{n\pi r}{\ln b-\ln a}=f(ae^r)$

$D(n)=\dfrac{1}{(\ln b-\ln a)\sinh\dfrac{n\pi^2}{2\ln b-2\ln a}}\int_0^{\ln b-\ln a}f(ae^r)\sin\dfrac{n\pi r}{\ln b-\ln a}dr$

$\therefore u(r,\theta)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{n\pi(\ln r-\ln a)}{\ln b-\ln a}\sinh\dfrac{n\pi\theta}{\ln b-\ln a}}{(\ln b-\ln a)\sinh\dfrac{n\pi^2}{2\ln b-2\ln a}}\int_0^{\ln b-\ln a}f(ae^r)\sin\dfrac{n\pi r}{\ln b-\ln a}dr$

Comment: This was very instructive, thanks... The manipulations in the first half of your post bring the problem through such an intriguing metamorphosis. The $r_1$ and $r_2$ substitutions seemed so curious at first that I actually started to laugh as everything resolved. Cool stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, with the fact that $a \neq b$,
$$\frac{\log(b)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})} - \frac{\log(a)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})} = \frac{\log(b) - \log(a)}{\log(b) - \log(a)} = 1$$

This tells that 
$$\frac{n\pi\log(b)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})} = n\pi +\frac{n\pi\log(a)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})}$$
 and that
$$\cos(\frac{n\pi\log(b)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})}) = (-1)^n\cos(\frac{n\pi\log(a)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})}) = 0 \text{ if } \cos(\frac{n\pi\log(a)}{\log(\frac{b}{a})}) = 0$$

Comment: That clears part of it up, thank you. Still, it seems that I then have to address this problem in three different cases after BCs: where sin,cos are nonzero, where cos()=0, and where sin()=0.

Comment: If, say $\cos(\phi) = 0$, then you just take $B$ = 0 and $A \in \mathbb{R}$. Vice versa if $\sin(\phi) = 0$.

Comment: I updated the question, as my query wasn't very focused. I'm mainly interested in whether all three of these cases result in the same overall solution to the *PDE* or if there are three different scenarios.